# Why does a ${\bf B}$-field follow a high $\mu$ core in an electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vector-fields, boundary-conditions

I'm having a hard time trying to understand why ${\bf B}$-field lines tend to follow the path of a high $\mu$ material.  Below is what actually happens when you apply a coil with some current around a high $\mu$ core:

[image: B-field inside circular magnetic material]

But why can the field lines not do something like this:

[image]

I understand the reason has something to do with boundary conditions ${\bf B}$ must obey when encountering a boundary (${\bf B}_\parallel$ discontinuous, ${\bf B}_\perp$ continuous).  If $\mu_\text{in}\gg\mu_\text{out}$, then we get the following conditions at any boundary between the high $\mu$ material and the air:
\begin{align}
{\bf B}_{\text{in},\perp}={\bf B}_{\text{out},\perp}\\
\frac{{\bf B}_{\text{in},\parallel}}{\mu_\text{in}}=\frac{{\bf B}_{\text{out},\parallel}}{\mu_\text{out}}
\end{align}
This tells me that ${\bf B}_{\text{out},\parallel}$ is effectively $0$ and maybe goes some way to explaining why there's no ${\bf B}$-field outside, but I can't rationalise why ${\bf B}_{\text{out},\perp}$ would have to be $0$ (or small) as well?  Why can't this happen:
[image]

Comment: [in response to a deleted comment] I'm also asking to see where mathematically $\mu$ says to ${\bf B}$ "stay in the material".

Answer (score 1):

Steady current flow and magnetostatics are entirely analogous and described by the exact same equations, with the following correspondences:
$$ \vec J\text{ (current density)} \longleftrightarrow \vec B $$
$$ \vec E\text{ (electric field)} \longleftrightarrow \vec H $$
$$ \vec\nabla\cdot\vec J = 0\text{ (continuity equation)} \longleftrightarrow \vec\nabla\cdot\vec B = 0 \text{ (Gauss' law)}$$
$$ \vec\nabla\times\vec E = -\frac{\partial\vec B}{\partial t}\text{ (Faraday's law)} \longleftrightarrow \vec\nabla\times\vec H = \vec J \text{ (Ampere's law)}$$
$$I \text{ (electric current)} \longleftrightarrow \mathcal{\Phi} \text{ (magnetic flux)}$$
$$R \text{ (electric resistance)} \longleftrightarrow \mathcal{R} \text{ (magnetic reluctance)}$$
$$\mathcal E \text{ (electromotive force)} \longleftrightarrow \mathcal{F} \text{ (magnetomotive force)}$$
$$\mathcal \sigma \text{ (electrical conductivity)} \longleftrightarrow \mathcal{\mu} \text{ (permeability)}$$
$$\vec J=\sigma\vec E \text{ (Ohm's law)} \longleftrightarrow \vec B=\mu\vec H \text{ (linear material constitutive equation)} $$

In the magnetic circuit you show, the high permeability core provides a low reluctance path for magnetic flux to "flow", and thus the flux remains confined to it. This is analogous to how a metal wire provides a low resistance path for electric current, thus confining it. The current-carrying winding here provides the magnetomotive force, while in the electrical analogy, you might have a battery providing the electromotive force.

Comment: I hadn't considered comparing $\mu$ to $\sigma$.  I have a problem though that in circuits, we have physical electrons moving around, blocked by high resistance.  In magnets, what exactly is moving around and being blocked?

Comment: There is nothing really moving, this is a mathematical analogy.