# Magnetization Enhancement Using Various Materials

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics

I was looking online at how inserting a material inside a solenoid can enhance/reduce the magnitude of a magnetic field in all space depending on what material is inserted. This makes sense from a diagram that I was looking at:

[image]

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/elemag.html#c4

And it also makes sense mathematically for the region inside the solenoid since one is just altering the mu value. But what doesn't make sense is how this mathematically also enhances the magnitude of the B field in the space (assuming vacuum) around the solenoid. Again, I understand conceptually thanks to the diagram why this is occurring. But from what I see when I look at the equation for the B field along the z axis:

$B_{\rho} = \frac{\mu_{0}I}{4\pi}\frac{1}{l\rho} [\sqrt((R+\rho)^2+\gamma^2)((m-2)K(m)+2E(m))]$

$B_{z} = \frac{\mu_{0}I}{2\pi}\frac{1}{l} [\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt((R+\rho)^2+\gamma^2)}(K(m)+\frac{R-\rho}{R+\rho}\prod(n,m))]$

Both evaluated at ${-\gamma}$ and ${\gamma}$. (Gave up trying to figure out the Latex code that worked for this since all options I could find threw an error)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid

Is that the mu value (Assume the m0 becomes mu) is only applicable for the point of interest. So, if I am looking at a point outside the solenoid, then m0 is applicable to that point and not mu. Therefore, I would think then that B would need to be broken up because mu0 would become a function mu(x,y,z) that represents the volume of the material. Subsequently, this would create a B field, piecewise equation that describes it in all space. Please help me understand why this is an incorrect interpretation (I assume it is wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations you have are valid only in free space, or when the entire space (inside the solenoid and outside) is uniform with permeability $\mu$, in which case you would replace $\mu_0$ in your equations with $\mu$. When you have $\mu$ that's a function of position, this is a different (and generally difficult) problem you need to solve separately: you can't just substitute $\mu(x, y, z)$ for $\mu_0$ in the free space solution.

As for why $\vec B$ is stronger in air when you have a magnetic core: there are a few ways to understand this. First, note that a boundary condition for magnetic fields is the continuity of the normal component of $\vec B$ across interfaces, which follows from Gauss' law $\vec\nabla\cdot\vec B = 0$. If you accept that $\vec B$ is larger in the solenoid with the magnetic core, since the normal component of $\vec B$ just outside the magnetic core at either pole is equal to that just inside the core, $\vec B$ in air just outside either pole is also larger.

More generally, such problems are often best viewed as [magnetic circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_circuit). Magnetostatics and steady current flow in electric circuits are entirely analogous mathematically: [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/704859/171547) for the details. You can think of the magnetic flux as electric current exiting the north pole and entering the south pole, $\vec B$ as current density, and the coil as a battery with voltage $NI$ where $N$ is the number of turns. Air is a much higher "resistance" medium (appropriately called reluctance in magnetic circuits) compared to a magnetic material with high $\mu$, so inserting a magnetic core greatly reduces the total reluctance of the magnetic circuit and increases the magnetic flux (in analogy with Ohm's law in electric circuits: resistance goes down, current goes up). Since whatever magnetic flux exists in the core must exit from the north pole, travel back through the air and enter the south pole, the magnetic flux and $\vec B$ in the air also increase.

Comment: So the solution for a solid cored, mu material solenoid cannot be described by just the equation that is shown in figure 1 because that is assuming that the entire space is that mu?

If I do wish to solve for the solenoid that has some mu not equal to mu0 and dependent on spatial position, does that mean having to solve for it using Biot-Savart but with extra steps (ie. Broken up by boundary conditions)?

Comment: Your explanation for flux is how I interpreted fig 1 that way, and that's why I am confused. Conceptually I do understand that this enforces a higher concentration of field lines in the mu0 space since it has to be continuous. The problem is I don't see how the math accounts for that change in B density in that space (Since it's using mu0 and not mu). Unless, that equation in fig 1 for the solid core is correct for all space. If it is, my next confusion is: If the magnetic field can be described by the mu. but it's permeating through a space that has a mu0 value, how is this self consistent?

Comment: You can't use the Biot-Savart law if you have a position dependent permeability. You need to solve the boundary value problem with the appropriate boundary conditions, which generally isn't easy and would often be done numerically. The field expressions in your figure are only valid inside an infinitely long solenoid, where the field is confined inside the solenoid and there is effectively no air since there is no field outside. In the case of a finite solenoid, you can't find the field either inside the magnetic core or in air by multiplying the vacuum solution by the relative permeability.

Comment: Now that makes sense. Do you have any resources that can help me learn about doing boundary value problems in magnetostatics? I already have looked at Jackson's section on this but would like more resources.

Comment: Also, conceptually (And based on the last paragraph of your answer) that means then that there is some kind of affect on the space around the finite solenoid. Just quantifying it is the difficult part.

Comment: I'm not aware of better references on solving boundary value problems unfortunately, maybe check out Griffiths. Note that certain kinds of magnetostatics problems simplify into a form identical to electrostatics problems, so the chapters of Jackson on solving electrostatic boundary value problems might also be relevant. You might want to ask a separate question on resource recommendations if you need more. And yes, changing the permeability of the core affects the field outside the solenoid.