# The mechanism of metal capturing magnetic flux

Tags: magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism

What is the mechanism of ferromagnetic object capturing magnetic flux?

For example, I learned that round metal is used in transformers to raise efficiency because the flux is carried through the metal.

Comment: It has nothing to do with metal. In fact, conductivity is detrimental to AC flux concentration. It is just by chance that many well-known ferromagnets happen to be metallic.

Answer (score 1):

The energy density of a field is:

$$ u = \frac{\vec B \cdot \vec H} 2 = \frac{\vec B \cdot \vec B}{2\mu}$$

So having field in media with $\mu \gt 1$ is energetically favorable.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand the sense in which energy is minimized. Note that we can also write $u=\frac 1 2 \mu H^2$. And as an example, an electromagnet (with fixed current) attracts magnetic materials, which reduces reluctance and *increases* magnetic energy. Any comments?

Comment: I'm just thinking of a static magnetic field. Now you're brought a source in: does it require energy to keep a fixed current? Let's say it's a super conductor...what happens with mutual induction? idk. Normally I ask leading question to which I know the answer, but here it's genuine.

Answer (score 0):

The equations that govern steady current flow and the "flow" of magnetic field lines are [essentially identical](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/704859/171547), allowing us to draw useful analogies between them. When you make a circuit by connecting a battery to some component(s) with wires, current is confined to these wires. This happens because the wires provide a low resistance path for current to flow in, due to their high electrical conductivity.

A [magnetic circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_circuit) works much the same way. A current-carrying wire wound around a transformer core acts like the
"battery" in this magnetic circuit. Due to its high [permeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)), the magnetic core confines the magnetic flux (the "current") by providing a low [reluctance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reluctance) path. Because of this property, when you wind two different coils around a good transformer core, you ensure that the flux through them is essentially the same.

Comment: I suppose $V=IR$ can be framed as an energy minimization, too.